# how to create 'my Friends activities' table for better reading performance

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

In a social website, I wanted to create a table in the sql server db to hold all friends activities, which will load in a page looks like facebook "News Feed", examples for these  activities:

- A friend added a photo
- A friend changed his profile picture
- A friend liked a photo
- A friend commented on a photo

so I created the following table:

```
Id  uniqueidentifier
UserId  uniqueidentifier -> The friend how did the activity
ObjectId    uniqueidentifier -> entity id which the user did the activity on such as photo id.
Type    int -> Type of the activity
CreatedOn   datetime 
Data    nvarchar(MAX) -> extra data about the object the user did the activity on.
```

But now While selecting from this table I should get all friends ids then select from this activities table using these ids or make a join.

What I hope is to get everything just from this table without going to the friends table, is that possible, and which columns i should add to make reading easier?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to select all friends for a particular user then join to this table to get the activities. I would also recommend that add an index on the userid, createdon columns which will speed up the processing